# Get user with specific age using date from database and carbon

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing requests when I want to get users with specific age. But I do not know how to get users from database. For example if user has 19 yo, I want users from age 12 - I get that user. If he has 20 - not. Can you help me with my code? Because it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
 if ($request->has('age_from')) 
        {
            $user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
                $birth_date = Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)->toDateString();

                return $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', $birth_date); 
            })->get();
        }
```

Comment: How is `date_of_birth` stored in your database? Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Camilo 1995-02-12 (year, day, month)

Comment: Add that info to your question.

Comment: What database are you using? How is your `date_of_birth` column defined? Add all of this info to your question.

Comment: @Camilo That's not relevant as Laravel works with Carbon objects and not necessarily date strings.

Comment: You don't need to add `return` in your subquery.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to format the `Carbon` object, Laravel and Carbon work seamlessly in database queries:

```
$user = User::with('user_data')->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request) { 
    $query->where('date_of_birth', '>=', Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)); 
})->get();
```

Comment: also $query->whereDate('date_of_birth', ... will do the trick

Comment: @Jeffrey when I try do to the same with age_to it doesnt work